# Switching Between Front to Back Cam is slow

Tags: android, android-camera, gpuimage

I'm using **GPUImageFilter** Library in my project and in a sample project, the switching between camera has done like this

```
View cameraSwitchView = findViewById(R.id.img_switch_camera);
cameraSwitchView.setOnClickListener(this);
if (!mCameraHelper.hasFrontCamera() || !mCameraHelper.hasBackCamera())
    cameraSwitchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I'm beginner in android development so i don't know how its working. Actually this thing is taking delay between switching .Anyone can help me to understand this code and tell me how to remove delay or suggest any other approach for speed up the switching time?